# Why is my minimum-coin calculator returning incorrect results for inputs of 0.41 and 4.2?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm on the cash problem of CS50x's pset1. The program is supposed to, given a float input, print the minimum number of coins (US) required to give change.  I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with my code. The program returns correct outputs for some values, like 23, 0.01, and 0.15, but returns incorrect values for, notably, 0.41 and 4.2, returning 3 and 22 respectively instead of 4 and 18. I've gone through this code lots of times but I can't find anything. The only thought I have is that there may be an issue with the floats getting rounded or truncated, but I don't really know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

float total_coins = 0;

float get_coin_amount(float amount, float coin_value);

int main(void)
{
    float change = get_float("Change owed: ");
    get_coin_amount(get_coin_amount(get_coin_amount(get_coin_amount(change, 0.25), 0.1), 0.05), 0.01);
    printf("%f\n", total_coins);
}

float get_coin_amount(float amount, float coin_value)
{
    float revised_amount = amount; //revised amount will be used to give a working total of the amount left
    while (revised_amount >= coin_value) //continue until the coin value can no longer go into the remaining amount
    {
        total_coins++; //update coins counter
        revised_amount = revised_amount - coin_value;//updates revised_amount
    }
    return revised_amount; //return remainder left after the coin goes into it as many times as possible
}
```

Comment: Most likely because you actually have $0.4099999999999999999 and $4.199999999999999 instead of $0.41 and $4.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using ints instead of floats.

i.e., multiply change by 100 and cast as int. Use 25, 10, 5, 1 for coin values. Otherwise looks solid.

Edit: Your solution is flawed. It does not actually return the correct number of coins at any point. Seems to only work with multiples of a single coin.

Should look more like this:

```
float get_coin_amount(float amount, float coin_value)
{
    float revised_amount = amount; //revised amount will be used to give a working total of the amount left
    while (revised_amount >= coin_value) //continue until the coin value can no longer go into the remaining amount
    {
        total_coins++; //update coins counter
        revised_amount = revised_amount - coin_value;//updates revised_amount
    }
    if (revised_amount > 0) {
        if (coin_value == 25) {
            return total_coins + get_coin_amount(revised_amount, 10);
        } else if (coin_value == 10) {
            return total_coins + get_coin_amount(revised_amount, 5);
        } else {
            return total_coins + get_coin_amount(revised_amount, 1);
        }
    } else {
        return total_coins;
    }
}
```

Then call the method something like this:

```
amount = (int) (get_float(...) * 100);
num_coins = get_coin_amount(amount, 25);
```

Comment: Part of the problem's specifications say that I must use the get_float function. Is there a way to turn the float I get from that function into an int?

Comment: @Gigabyte8 multiply by 100 and round, then cast to int.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: No need to round, just multiply by 100 and cast to int.

Comment: I just multiplied by 100 and cast to int, and my program works with 0.41 now, but it still returns 22 for 4.2. Thoughts?

Comment: I think you need to make some changes. See the edit I made.

Comment: You **do** need to round.

Comment: Ok you need to round

Comment: I was able to get the code working by rounding it. Thanks everyone for your help.